# Ublock Origin filter to block recommended videos on YouTube homepage?

Tags: youtube, ublock

I'm looking for a Ublock Origin custom filter that I can add that will permanently block the recommended videos section from showing on my YouTube homepage?

I tried blocking the recommended videos section using the "block element" picker, but it didn't work; each time the YouTube homepage is refreshed it comes back, the block doesn't stick.

I appreciate any help; thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
youtube.com##.section-list > li:has(.shelf-title-cell > a[href="/feed/recommended"])
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will work?

Comment: Through trial and error and looking at some other questions and responses around here (https://superuser.com/questions/514111/how-do-i-block-youtubes-suggested-videos/1014527), etc., I tried adding                            www.youtube.com##li:nth-of-type(2)      in the my filters list, it seems to work...so far...

Comment: Edit:  www.youtube.com##li:nth-of-type(2)    was causing other things to disappear that I didn't want to block so I had to delete it from the my filters list.

Comment: It works exactly. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

How about this to not show videos on the homepage alltogether:

```
youtube.com##.ytd-shelf-renderer
```

And this to hide recommendations next to a video:

```
youtube.com##.ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this one worked and removed the recommended videos at the start page without blocking other stuff (like videos on a channel).

```
www.youtube.com##.grid-disabled.ytd-browse.style-scope
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this one way more understandable: at "www.youtube.com" pick "dismissable" id element that has "title" id element which contains "Recommended" text.

```
www.youtube.com###dismissable:has(#title:contains(Recommended))
```