# Ublock Origin custom filter suddenly stopped working---it previously worked very well---any assistance?

Tags: youtube, ublock, ublock-origin

Until just recently, I had been using the Ublock Origin custom filter given by rhill in this post [Ublock Origin filter to block recommended videos on YouTube homepage?](https://superuser.com/questions/1165319/ublock-origin-filter-to-block-recommended-videos-on-youtube-homepage) to block the recommended videos section on the YouTube homepage.

Now that filter doesn't work anymore; I don't know why it would have just stopped working and become ineffective suddenly like that, when it had been working very well all the time before. I tried re-entering it as a custom filter and that didn't work. Blocking the recommended video section using the element picker doesn't work, the section always comes back when the page is reloaded.

Could anyone help me with a Ublock Origin filter that would block the recommended videos section on the Youtube homepage?

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: For reference, the filter that doesn't work anymore is: youtube.com##.section-list > li:has(.shelf-title-cell > a[href="/feed/recommended"])

Comment: Any ideas for a replacement filter?

Comment: The entire YouTube frontpage consists of recommendations. I recall I never found a filter that doesn't also hide search results and such. I've decided to avoid the frontpage.